# how to include or in a loop in batch script

Tags: batch-file

i'm trying to write in a folder the result of my my compilation : if there is one type of file (file1 or file2) it means that my compilation succeded. And I want to report this result in a txt file

I tried to do it with a flag using booleans but it just does not work. i'm parsing my folders and in each output/NameofaRun I'm looking if there is file1 or file2.

```
for /D %%X in (%1\*) do (
    set flag = 0
    if exist %%X\OUTPUT\%2\file1.txt ( flag = 1)
    if exist %%X\OUTPUT\%2\file2.txt ( flag = 1)
    if %flag% ==  1 ( echo %%X>>%3\Compilation_Check.txt Succeeded )
    if %flag% == 0 (
        echo %%X>>%3\Compilation_Check.txt Failed Warning
        )
)
```

I want to write in "compilation_check.txt" the result of my txt. and I'm running this batch with path to folders/name of folder as parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct; several details not...

- The `set` command get as variable name all characters before the equal sign *including spaces*. You should use `set flag=0` or, better yet, `set "flag=0"`.
- It is *convenient* to enclose file names between quotes in order to avoid problems if any name may include spaces...
- You missed the `set` command when you change `flag` value.
- When a variable value changes *inside a `(block)`*, the new value can not be accessed via `%var%`, but using `!var!` syntax AND including `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning of the program. There are *a lot* of detailed explanations about this point; look for "delayed expansion".

This is your code with previous modifications:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /D %%X in (%1\*) do (
    set "flag=0"
    if exist "%%X\OUTPUT\%2\file1.txt" ( set "flag=1" )
    if exist "%%X\OUTPUT\%2\file2.txt" ( set "flag=1" )
    if !flag! == 1 ( echo %%X Succeeded  >> "%3\Compilation_Check.txt")
    if !flag! == 0 (
        echo %%X Failed Warning  >> "%3\Compilation_Check.txt"
        )
)
```

However, I would do it this way:

```
for /D %%X in (%1\*) do (
    set "anyFile="
    if exist "%%X\OUTPUT\%2\file1.txt" set "anyFile=1"
    if exist "%%X\OUTPUT\%2\file2.txt" set "anyFile=1"
    (if defined anyFile ( 
        echo %%X Succeeded
    ) else (
        echo %%X Failed Warning
    )) >> "%3\Compilation_Check.txt"
)
```

You are not using *the value* of `flag` variable. The `if defined` command allows to check for the existence of a variable; this "trick" allows to avoid the Delayed Expansion problem...

You may enclose several commands in a `(block)` so the output of all of them is redirected to the same file...

Comment: I would recommend the use of `%~1`, `%~2` and `%~3` too, _(in the `For` loop parentheses that would obviously mean using `"%~1\*"`_.